# Changing the precision of data in a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of matrices

```
a = {{{1, 0.0027439,  0.145732, 0.231707,31.8}},
     {{1, 0.00275229, 0.146177, 0.232416, 31.7}}, 
     {{1, 0.00276074, 0.146626, 0.233129, 31.6}}, 
     {{1, 0.00276923, 0.147385, 0.233846, 31.5}}, 
     {{1, 0.00277778, 0.14784,  0.234568, 31.4}}, 
     {{1, 0.00278638, 0.148297, 0.235294, 31.3}}}
```

For the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of each row, I want to only keep 2 places after the decimal, so the list looks like

```
anew={{{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.23, 31.8}}, 
      {{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.23, 31.7}}, 
      {{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.23, 31.6}}, 
      {{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.23, 31.5}},
      {{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.23, 31.4}},
      {{1, 0.00, 0.15, 0.24, 31.3}}}
```

I have tried applying `pa = PaddedForm[a[[All, All, {2, 3, 4}]], {2, 2}]` but the output is simply the list of 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements. How do I retain the 1st and 5th element in the output as shown above?

Thanks

**EDIT 1**
Since my approach with `PaddedForm` is sort of the right result, but is missing the 1st and 5th elements, I was wondering a naive way might be to join `a[[All, All, 1]` and `a[[All, All, 5]]` to `pa`. Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT 2**
I am only trying to plot these data points, therefore the exact form of the numbers shown is not necessary.

Comment: See my comments on the answer below - is this for display only, or do you want to later operate on the results? Treating numbers massaged for display as just numbers can open a whole can of worms...

Comment: I understand that you want to plot these values. I wonder, are you sure that you want to *reduce* the precision of your data? You are losing some information that way.

Comment: The idea is, these are particles that move very slightly as time progresses. I am not interested in their movements, so I am reducing the precision of the data to "hide" these movements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round the 2nd through 4th *row*, try:

```
MapAt[Round[#, .01] &, a, {{2}, {3}, {4}}]
```

or

```
MapAt[Round[#, .01] &, a, {#} & /@ Range[2, 4]]
```

or

```
MapAt[Round[#, .01] &, a, List /@ Range[2, 4]]
```

Output:

```
{{{1, 0.0027439, 0.145732, 0.231707, 31.8}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.7}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.6}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.5}}, 
 {{1, 0.00277778, 0.14784, 0.234568, 31.4}}, 
 {{1, 0.00278638, 0.148297, 0.235294, 31.3}}}
```

If you want to round the 2nd through 4th element in each row:

```
Map[Round[#, .01] &, a]

{{{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.8}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.7}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.6}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.5}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.4}}, 
 {{1., 0., 0.15, 0.24, 31.3}}}
```

Comment: Neither of these seems to produce the desired result, am I missing something?

Comment: Look at the OP *anew*... "For the 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of *each row*". In addition, *0.* is not *0.00*, nor is *1.* *1*, though I think the OP needs to clarify if this is for display purposes only, or they want to do calculations against it - the latter form can be had via *numberform*, etc, but that may cause machinations later...

Comment: The last one works! Thanks!:)

Comment: @ciao Thanks for your comments. I am trying to plot these data. Do you think I will run into problems later?

Comment: No need to map, just `Round[a,.01]`. Poor example in OP, much back-and-forth could have been saved by making it clear an exact first element (as shown in the example) was not needed. Ugh.

Comment: @HuShu: No, since this is actually rounding (and see my comment above - no need to map). But your example shows *exact* first elements (not rounded), and *0.00*, not *0.*, so a reader would be lead to believe you needed it that way. could have saved time and effort stating that was not the case, then `Round[a,.01]` suffices....

Comment: I didn't know about `Round`, I was initially led by `PaddedForm` that's why my example had such exact numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to David's approach with `Map`, you could also extract those parts of the matrices whose precision you want to change, and then use the rounded values to update the values in the original matrices:

```
a[[All, All, 2 ;;]] = Round[a[[All, All, 2 ;;]], 0.01]

(* Out:
{{{1, 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.8}},
 {{1, 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.7}},
 {{1, 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.6}},
 {{1, 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.5}},
 {{1, 0., 0.15, 0.23, 31.4}},
 {{1, 0., 0.15, 0.24, 31.3}}}
*)
```

---

If, as you say in comments, you are just going to plot these values, then you don't care about the precision of the first value. In that case, the much simpler `Round[a, 0.01]` will do just fine!

Comment: Yes, my bad. I did that manually, and missed that.